# Array formatting in php (used laravel framework)

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I am trying to format an array in php . It does not return in expected json format . Here is details.

```
$categories = category::where('cat_flag','Y')->pluck('cat_name as category_name')->toArray();
$items = item::leftjoin('categories','items.cat_id' ,'=', 'categories.id')
                      ->where('item_flag','Y')
                      ->get([
                            'item_name',
                            'items.cat_id as category_id',
                            'cat_name as category_name'
                        ])->toArray();

        $formatedArray = [];
        foreach ($categories as $category) {
            foreach ($items as $item) {
                if ($item['category_name'] == $category) {
                    $formatedArray['cat_name'] = $category;
                    $formatedArray['datas'][] = $item;
                }
            }
        }
```

my expected output is like bellow. but there is logical error in array format part . I am not getting properly how to format that. Thanks in advance

```
       [
         {
           "cat_name" : "food",
           "datas" : [
                {
                  "item_name": "item2",
                  "category_id": "1"
                },
                {
                  "item_name": "item4",
                  "category_id": "1"
                }
             ]
           },
           {
           "cat_name" : "drinks",
           "datas" : [
                {
                  "item_name": "coca cola",
                  "category_id": "4"
                }
             ]
           }
        ]
```

But my output showing like . All items are in same category

```
  {
"cat_name": "cat4",
"datas": [
    {
        "item_name": "item2",
        "category_id": "1"
    },
    {
        "item_name": "item22",
        "category_id": "2"
    }
 ]
}
```

Comment: what is the formatting error?

Comment: no error showing. I can't set **"cat_name" : "food"**  this object . It just set once . But i want to mentioned format . Thanks for reply

Comment: in if you should $category->category_name not just $category maybe that is posint

Answer (score 1):

Hey dude try this you are comparing string to object

```
foreach ($categories as $category) {
        foreach ($items as $item) {
            if ($item['category_name'] == $category) {
                if(!empty($formatedArray)){
                  foreach(formatedArray as $array){
                     if(!empty($array) && $array['cat_name']  == $category){
                          array_push($formatedArray['datas'], $item)
                     }else{
                          $newArray = [];
                          $newArray['cat_name'] = $category;
                          $newArray['datas'][] = $item;
                          array_push($formatedArray, $newArray);
                     }
                  }
                }else{
                  $formatedArray['cat_name'] = $category;
                  $formatedArray['datas'][] = $item
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Thanks for reply. It was array that's why I converted into array like $category['category_name'] . But it showing  **Illegal string offset 'category_name'**

Comment: @Mithun updated look at this did you mean like that

Comment: Thanks for giving me time. But again **Illegal string offset 'category_name'**

Comment: can you show me few example from database for both table

Comment: $Categories = array:2 [
  0 => "cat2"
  1 => "cat4"
]

Comment: $items = array:5 [
  0 => array:7 [
    "item_name" => "item2"
    "category_id" => "1"
    "category_name" => "cat2"
  ]
  1 => array:7 [
    "item_name" => "item4"
    "category_id" => "2"
    "category_name" => "cat4"
  ]
  2 => array:7 [
    "item_name" => "item22"
    "category_id" => "1"
    "category_name" => "cat2"
  ]
]

Comment: check this out @Mithun

Comment: Thanks for giving your valuable time. It shows **Illegal string offset 'category_name'**. But I have this

Comment: it was exactly what you write i changed only algorithm

Comment: showing error in **if(!empty($array) && $array['category_name']  == $category){** this line

Comment: if I comment out **$array['category_name']  == $category** condition then it works. but not expected result

Comment: but i did not write like what you said i wrote !empty($array) && $array['cat_name']  == $category

Comment: I think there is no category_name index create in $array['category_name']

Comment: yes. I set **$formatedArray = [];** top of foreach loop. is it ok ?

Answer (score 1):

I think the following code is the problem:
In each iteration, $formattedArray contents are being replaced with new values!

```
$formatedArray = [];
        foreach ($categories as $category) {
            foreach ($items as $item) {
                if ($item['category_name'] == $category) {
                    $formatedArray['cat_name'] = $category;
                    $formatedArray['datas'][] = $item;
                }
            }
        }
```

Replace the above with this:

```
$formatedArray = $thisArray = [];
        foreach ($categories as $category) {
            foreach ($items as $item) {
                if ($item['category_name'] == $category) {
                    $thisArray['cat_name'] = $category;
                    $thisArray['datas'][] = $item;
                    $formatedArray[] = $thisArray;
                    $thisArray = [];
                }
            }
        }
```

Comment: Thanks for reply . But It separates same category into multiple. I need same Items under same category

Comment: {
        "cat_name": "cat2",
        "datas": [
            {
                "item_name": "item2",
                "category_id": "1"
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "cat_name": "cat2",
        "datas": [
            {
                "item_name": "item22",
                "category_id": "1"
            }
        ]
    },

Comment: But I need like bellow comment

Comment: {
    "cat_name": "cat2",
    "datas": [
            {
                "item_name": "item2",
                "category_id": "1"
            },
   {
                "item_name": "item22",
                "category_id": "1"
            }
        ]
}